# chain of promsies to make a state machine?

Tags: javascript, promise, state-machine

I have this pattern: (where (Pi) are different promsies)

```
// STEP 1 : Show the help modal and the instruction modal after.
P1.then(() => {
  return P2
})

// STEP 2 : Start calibration 
.then(() => {
  return P3;
})

// STEP 3 : Wait until all points have been clicked on
.then(() => {
  doSomething();
});
```

I made a sort of State Machine.
At the end, in doSomething() I want to go back to my second then IF the calibration wasn't a success, or end the chain otherwise.

I don't know how to do it... Do you have an idea?

Comment: You cannot really "go back" The promises are not reusable in this way. Each promise chain is supposed to fire once and that's it. If you want to execute *the same logic*, you might want to produce another equivalent promise chain. Although, given that you seem to have a state machine, you could probably implement it so that transitions are the promise producing operations and the state is the result of the promise.

Comment: If you need a state machine to use, you could look at https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. It's what I thought, I'm going to have to change my whole logic :(
@andymccullough don't you think that the TKoL solution would be better than this one which seems complicated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about something like this:

```js
const steps = {
  one: async () => {
    await something();
    steps.two();
  }
  
  two: async () => {
    try {
      const results = await somethingElse();
      steps.three(results);
    } catch(e) {
      // TODO display error message
      steps.one();
    }    
  }
  
  three: async () => {
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

Don't know if a structure like that might help you.

Comment: It seems like a good idea!
 I wonder why I would have to use this : https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate because your solutions seems good.

Comment: @PaulSerre you don't HAVE to use it. It's just a library for producing and working with state machines. You can implement state machine by yourself - they are not very complex. However, if you are going to be implementing stat machines, that's a great gateway to using even more state machines - you'll soon realise how many problems are representable as a FSM and how it's easier to tackle them at that point. If you intend to actually *implement* them as an FSM, then why not use a library instead of hand-making each one?

Comment: I want to make te clearest code possible, so I wanted to know if it was more understandable to use this library. Thanks for your help all.